# Grab the @gmail.com from a email input

Tags: php, html

Had a good xmas i hope. If so , how would i go about grabbing the @gmail from the following input.... I have it as a variable after inpt. But how would i grab the @gmail.com part so i can use it in a activation icon.. thanks...

I give you the full code but obviously i just require a short code to eliminate the input before the @ .

```
    if (isset($_POST['email'])){
        $email = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
        //use this for any input to be stored in the database - to eliminate any html or script tags
        $email = htmlspecialchars($email, ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8'); 
        if (preg_match ("%^[A-Za-z0-9._\%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$%", stripslashes(trim($_POST['email'])))) {
        $email = htmlentities($_POST['email'] ); 
        $email = filter_var($email, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
        //escape chars - basically escapes such chars as ' or " or # ect ect with a slash//
        $email = strip_tags($email);}

$email2use = strip this stuff <myemail> <grab the following===@gmail.com > & result = $email2use
```

Thanks for any enlightenments.

Comment: `filter_var` does all you do before that already! To get rid of the first part just explode by '@' and take the second item in the resulting array

Comment: Sorry Cookie, But im getting annoyed with these friggin typo warriors. i update accordingly anyway.,

Comment: Yea I had a bad Xmas mate.

Comment: And please don't use vulgar words in your edits, I could flag it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use substr and strrippos functions to capture the emails.

```
$email = strip_tags($email);
echo substr($email,strripos($email,"@"));
```

Comment: $email= "russbakker2016@gmail.com";

$gotmail =  substr($email,strripos($email,"@"));

echo $gotmail;

die();

Comment: How do i go further and grab without the @ - i need the Gmail.com part

Comment: substr($email,strripos($email,"@")+1);